# django autocomplete light on admin: how does it work?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to make searcheable customer foreigkey on model on admin.

I has installed Django autocomplete light, but i can`t see works.

I'm trying this.

**admin.py**

```
import autocomplete_light

class RedAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Red
        widget = {'customer': autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('CustomerAutocomplete')}


class RedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #form = RedAdminForm
    list_display = ("id", "customer","sponsor")
    list_per_page = 10
    search_fields=['customer__username', 'sponsor__username']
    #raw_id_fields = ('customer','sponsor',)
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Red)

admin.site.register(Red, RedAdmin)
```

I also have all css and js static files of module, has installed and put on installed apps.

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

autocomplete_light.register(User)
```

**show error on ajax request:**

```
FieldError at /autocomplete/UserAutocomplete/ Cannot resolve keyword u'name' into field. Choices are:
```

Comment: Can anyone help me in editing the language here? Some sentences seem to be so weird that I'm not sure what their meaning is.

Comment: have you added autocomplete in installed app in your settings.py file

Comment: yes, i has added and has make collecstatic

Comment: show error: FieldError at /autocomplete/UserAutocomplete/ Cannot resolve keyword u'name' into field. Choices are:

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, autocomplete-light doesn't reuse the ModelAdmin's search_fields. There's an [open PR for that](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/pull/361).

Try registering with search_fields ie.:

```
registry.register(User, search_fields=['username', 'email'])
```